# OSx gnuplot '-persist' option does not work inside gnu environment

Tags: macos, terminal, gnuplot

I've installed gnuplot on my Mac and its terminal is set to x11. When I try to create a basic plot:

```
gnuplot
plot sin(x)
```

The new window immediately opens up and closes again. After some online research, it seems that the '-persist' option is the way to deal with this, but it does not work in all situations. For example, if I enter the following:

```
gnuplot -persist -e 'plot sin(x)'
```

It generates the plot perfectly. But if I do this:

```
gnuplot -persist
plot sin(x)
```

It does the same thing as before where the window closes immediately. This is also true if I try:

```
gnuplot
set terminal x11 persist
plot sin(x)
```

Is there a way to deal with this so that it works in all cases?

Comment: My manpage suggests it is `gnuplot --persist` i.e. with double dashes.

Comment: What does "inside gnu environment" mean? If you start gnuplot and enter `plot sin(x)`, does the plot window show up and then immediately close, but you are still in the gnuplot session (i.e, the prompt is `gnuplot>`)?

Comment: @MarkSetchell - I have used double dashes as well. The behavior is identical.

Comment: @user8153 by "inside gnu environment" I mean that I open up a gnuplot session, and then enter "plot sin(x)". This causes the window to open up and close immediately. I am still in the gnuplot session at this point (i.e. I have not entered "exit" yet).

Comment: More of an aside than an answer, but I use `brew install gnuplot --with-qt` and the resulting plot windows are much better and can be zoomed, and copied to clipboard and saved as files from the additional menu options you get over and above X11.